# Find closest element

Tags: jquery

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="widgets">
                <div class="rating_block">
                    <span class="iFoot fMin"><%= film.GoingCount %></span>
                    <div class="stars_rating">
                        <div class="stars_off"></div>
                        <div class="stars_on"></div>
                    </div><!-- .stars_rating-->

                    <span class="num_rating">(<%= film.Rating %>)</span>
                    <div class="expand"></div>
                </div><!-- .rating_block-->

                <div class="voice_block">
                    <div class="going" filmid="<%=film.OID %>">
                        <a href="">I'm going!</a>
                        <div id="going_too">Going too: <%= film.GoingCount %></div>
                    </div><!-- .going-->

                    <div class="data_for_rating">
                        <div>Vote</div>
                            <div class="star_for_rating">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">3</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">4</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">5</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- .star_for_rating-->
                        <div>Average: 4,5 (89)</div>
                    </div><!-- .data_for_rating-->
                </div><!-- .voice_block-->
            </div><!-- .widgets-->
```

My js function:

```
function setUpUpdateGoingCount() {
            $("div.going a").click(function (e) {
                var goingToo = $(this);
                e.preventDefault();
                var filmId = $(this).parent("div").attr("filmid");
                $.post("/Cinema/UpdateGoingCount", { id: filmId }, function (obj) {
                    if (obj.Success) {
                        goingToo.parent("div").find("#going_too").text("going too: " + obj.Result); //work
                        goingToo.closest(".rating_block").find(".iFoot.fMin").text(obj.Result); //not work
                    }

                });
            });
        };
```

Why jquery can't find `span` with class `iFoot.fMin` ?
I am using `closest` because this block (`widget`) may be several.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`goingToo.closest(".rating_block")` should be the problem here.

Closest works like this:

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

By progressing up through the DOM tree, there won't be a `.rating_block`, only `.voice_block`

You could do the following instead:

```
goingToo.closest(".voice_block").prev(".rating_block").find(".iFoot.fMin")
```

Which will grab the closest `.voice_block`, and then the previous sibling with the class `rating_block`

Comment: Thanks, it's working. but I think this is better: goingToo.closest(".widgets").find(".iFoot.fMin").text(obj.Result);

Comment: It is, assuming that `.widgets` doesn't contain several rating and voice blocks, in which case I'd go with the solution I suggested.